# Optimize SQLite search

Tags: sqlite, search, optimization

I have a database with contact data from around 250.000 people.

This is what I do, to search a name. The search should include first and lastname and the searchstring should be at the beginning of the first or lastname:

```
SELECT contacts.firstName, contacts.lastName
FROM contacts
WHERE (contacts.lastName LIKE '" + searchstring + "%') OR (contacts.firstName LIKE '" + searchstring + "%')"
ORDER BY lastName, firstName";
```

This brings up the required results, but a searchs duration is around 5 secs which is way to much.
I think there is a lot of potential to optimize this search. Do you have any sources or tips for me?

Comment: Step #1 - always let your software utilize your hardware to the fullest. Step #2 - optimize the algorithm in place. Now, you're trying to optimize the algorithm but you obviously need it to work as described with your query. That means you can do two things - first is optimize MySQL configuration and let it store working data set in RAM. That makes the search really, really quick. Second is that you can try and index `lastName` and `firstName`. What I'm suspecting is that you're probably using default MySQL configuration.

Comment: The OR is probably stopping MySQL using any indexes on lastname or firstname. Split this in to 2 queries unioned together, one to check the last name and one to check the first name.

Comment: Index `contacts.lastName` and `contacts.firstName`.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I was able to optimizing the performance significantly with your help